# parsing ip address in raw socket programming in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip-address

I am implementing raw sockets in C linux. I am new to socket programming so have some problem with the data types to be used for Internet addresses.

I want to know what should be the data type of ip_addres(in main) in my code below. I think it needs to be pointer as I need to return two addresses. Then these two addresses are to be passed in the next function as shown.

```
main()
{
       int len,raw_socket;
       struct iphdr *ip_header;
       unsigned char *packet_buffer[2048];
       len=recvfrom(raw_socket,packet_buffer,2048,...);

       ip_addres=parseipheader(packet_buffer,len); /*I want this function to return ip address of destination and source*/
       ip_header=CreateIPHeader(source_ip,destination_ip);
}

parseipheader(unsigned char *packet,int len)
{
       struct iphdr *ip_header;
       ip_header=(struct ip_header *)(packet+sizeof(struct ethhdr));
       return ip_addresses;
}
struct iphdr* CreateIPHeader(source_ip,destination_ip)
{
       struct iphdr *ip_header;

       return ip_header;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct . You can return pointer to the source ip address and destination ip address is 4 bytes (32 bits) from source ip address in ip header . so you can add 4 to the address of source ip address to get the destination ip address .

char *src_ip;

src_ip = parseipheader(packet_buffer,len);

CreateIPHeader(src_ip,src_ip+4);